# C++ : No warning for unused local constants with /W4 (MSVC)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, build, compilation, constants

*The following code was compiled with MSVC 19.29.30133.0*

Given the following c++ line in a function

```cpp
int foo = 0;
```

If the variable isn't referenced, MSCV will give you the following warning: `warning C4189: 'foo': local variable is initialized but not referenced`

However, if `const` is added in front of it, the warning disappears.

```cpp
const int foo = 0; // <<--This line yields no warning with MSVC 19.29.30133.0
```

But this unused variable should still be removed, isn't it?

So why is it that MSVC gives no warning? Is it a bug, is there a specification for unused constants?

minimal reproduction:

```cpp
int main() {
    int a = 0;
    const int b = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Starting build...
cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /nologo /W4 /std:c++20 /Fe: F:\prog\INF1005C\tst\unused_constant.exe F:\prog\INF1005C\tst\unused_constant.cpp
unused_constant.cpp

F:\prog\INF1005C\tst\unused_constant.cpp(2): warning C4189: 'a': local variable is initialized but not referenced

Build finished with warning(s).
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd imagine it's common for headers to define constants this way, and it would be annoying if you had warnings every time you included, say, a library header.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It happens for function-scoped local constants too. Not only for global constants.

Comment: Can not reproduce this problem. Using VS2022 (19.30.30706) i'm getting C4189 in both situations. So perhaps you should upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: @user7860670 See my minimal reproducible example. The difference is unlikely to be between msvc 19.29 and 19.30.

Comment: With VS2022  this example produces C4189 warnings for both `a` and `b`.